# How do you set the time on a variable once set with a Date in VBA

Tags: vba, datetime

Once I have set the `tad` variable to a date as in the following code, how do I set set the time on the variable?

```
Private Sub TimeAndDate()

    Dim tad As Date
    
    tad = Date
    
    'set var tad time < somehow
    
End Sub
```

I can see it is quite easy to set to a specific date, using `now` or `format` functions but once set to a date, I cannot see how you'd set the time.

Comment: Check this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_date_time.htm#:~:text=Time%20Functions,-Sr.No.&text=A%20Function%2C%20which%20returns%20the%20current%20system%20date%20and%20time.&text=A%20Function%2C%20which%20returns%20an%20integer%20between%200%20and%2023,part%20of%20the%20given%20time.&text=A%20Function%2C%20which%20returns%20an%20integer%20between%200%20and%2059,part%20of%20the%20given%20time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply *add* the time value to the date value:

```vb
Private Sub TimeAndDate()

    Dim tad As Date
    Dim tat As Date
    
    tad = Date
    tat = Time  ' Or your time value.
    
    ' Combine date and time.
    tad = tad + tat

    ' or for adding time from a combined date and time value.
    ' tad = tad + TimeValue(tat)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What if `tad=date` was changed to `tad=now` which might happen if set to a specific time/date.  What happens then is time `tat` is added to the time in `tad` which would alter the time and potentially the date too if it pushes in to the next day.
Is there any way to alter just the time part of the variable in case this is already set?

Comment: See expanded answer, please.